# Add sections from a JSON file to a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Good morning, everyone, 
I have created a TableView that uses data from a JSON file. 
I can put my data in my TableView with Alamofire, but for ease of reference I would like to sort them by section with date. 
Because for each date over 15 days there are weather forecasts for each hour. 
So ideally I would like a section per day that opens with the click and gives every hour with forecasts.

This is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import MapKit

class WeatherProController: UIViewController,  CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate  {

private let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

var datas = [WeatherProData]()
var locManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentLocation: CLLocation!

var timer = Timer()
var jour = UIColor(red: 0, green: 191 / 255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
var nuit = UIColor(red: 51 / 255, green: 116 / 255, blue: 255 / 255, alpha: 1)

let didBecomeActiveNotificationName = UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification

let identifiantCell = "dataProCell"
let identifiantSegue = "versDetailDonneePro"

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    locManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(scheduleTimer), name: didBecomeActiveNotificationName, object: nil)
    changeBackground()
    data()

    // Add Refresh Control to Table View
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    } else {
        tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
    // Configure Refresh Control
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshWeatherData(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.white
    let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Refreshing please wait", attributes: attributes)

}

@objc private func refreshWeatherData(_ sender: Any) {
    fetchWeatherData()
}

private func setupActivityIndicatorView() {
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
}

private func fetchWeatherData() {
    data()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
  // self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
}

@objc func scheduleTimer() {
    // schedule the timer
    timer = Timer(fireAt: Calendar.current.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: DateComponents(hour: 6..<21 ~= Date().hour ? 21 : 6), matchingPolicy: .nextTime)!, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(changeBackground), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    print(timer.fireDate)
    //        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .RunLoop.Mode.common)
    print("new background chenge scheduled at:", timer.fireDate.description(with: .current))
}

@objc func changeBackground(){
    // check if day or night shift
    self.view.backgroundColor =  6..<21 ~= Date().hour ? jour : nuit
    // schedule the timer
    scheduleTimer()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return datas.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifiantCell) as? WeatherProCell {
        let data = datas[indexPath.row]
        cell.creerCell(data)
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? WeatherProCell {
        cell.textIsHidden.isHidden = !cell.textIsHidden.isHidden
        cell.textIsHidden1.isHidden = !cell.textIsHidden1.isHidden
        cell.textIsHidden2.isHidden = !cell.textIsHidden2.isHidden
        cell.textIsHidden3.isHidden = !cell.textIsHidden3.isHidden
        cell.textIsHidden4.isHidden = !cell.textIsHidden4.isHidden
        cell.textIsHidden5.isHidden = !cell.textIsHidden5.isHidden
        cell.textIsHidden6.isHidden = !cell.textIsHidden6.isHidden
        cell.textIsHidden7.isHidden = !cell.textIsHidden7.isHidden
        cell.textIsHidden8.isHidden = !cell.textIsHidden8.isHidden
        cell.textIsHidden9.isHidden = !cell.textIsHidden9.isHidden
        cell.cloud.isHidden = !cell.cloud.isHidden
        cell.rTemp.isHidden = !cell.rTemp.isHidden
        cell.cloudBase.isHidden = !cell.cloudBase.isHidden
        cell.dewp.isHidden = !cell.dewp.isHidden
        cell.press.isHidden = !cell.press.isHidden
        cell.pressIcon.isHidden = !cell.pressIcon.isHidden
        cell.hydro.isHidden = !cell.hydro.isHidden
        cell.hydroIcon.isHidden = !cell.hydroIcon.isHidden
        cell.vent.isHidden = !cell.vent.isHidden
        cell.ventIcon.isHidden = !cell.ventIcon.isHidden
        cell.rainIcon.isHidden = !cell.rainIcon.isHidden
        cell.rain.isHidden = !cell.rain.isHidden
        cell.iso0.isHidden = !cell.iso0.isHidden
        cell.freezeRain.isHidden = !cell.freezeRain.isHidden
        cell.noSnow.isHidden = !cell.noSnow.isHidden
        cell.snowUp.isHidden = !cell.snowUp.isHidden
        cell.visibility.isHidden = !cell.visibility.isHidden
        cell.snowProb.isHidden = !cell.snowProb.isHidden

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}

//func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
 //  return datas.count
//}

//func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection    section: Int) -> String? {
   // return datas[section].date
//}

func data() {
    if ( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse ||
        CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways) {
        currentLocation = locManager.location
    }

    var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]

    let user = loginWeatherPro
    let password = motDePasseWeatherPro

    if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: user, password: password) {
        headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
    }

    let now = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC")
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    print(formatter.string(from: now))
    let days = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 15, to: now)

    let urlB = urlDeBaseWeatherPro
    let locate = "locatedAt=\(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude),\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
    let period = "&validPeriod=PT0S"
    let validFrom = "&validFrom=\(formatter.string(from: now))"
    let validUntil = "&validUntil=\(formatter.string(from: days!))"
    let fields = "&fields=" + fieldsParameter
    let url = urlB + locate + period + validFrom + validUntil + fields
    print(url)

    Alamofire.request(url, headers:headers).responseJSON{ response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let forecast = JSON ["forecasts"] as? NSArray {
                for element in forecast {
                    if let dict = element as? [String: AnyObject],
                        let dates = dict ["validFrom"] as? String ,
                        let weatherCode = dict ["weatherCode"] as? Int ,
                        let weatherCodeString = weatherCodesTab[weatherCode],
                        let temp = dict ["airTemperatureInCelsius"] as? Double ,
                        let cloud = dict ["effectiveCloudCoverInPercent"] as? Double ,
                        let rtemp = dict ["feelsLikeTemperatureInCelsius"] as? Double ,
                        let cloudBase = dict ["cloudBaseHeightInMeter"] as? Double ,
                        let dewp = dict ["dewPointTemperatureInCelsius"] as? Double ,
                        let press = dict ["airPressureAtSeaLevelInHectoPascal"] as? Double ,
                        let hydro = dict ["relativeHumidityInPercent"] as? Double ,
                        let vent = dict ["windSpeedInKilometerPerHour"] as? Double ,
                        let rain = dict ["precipitationProbabilityInPercent"] as? Double ,
                        let iso0 = dict ["freezingLevelHeightInMeter"] as? Double ,
                        let freezeRain = dict ["freezingRainProbabilityInPercent"] as? Double ,
                        let noSnow = dict ["noSnowPossibleBelowHeightInMeter"] as? Double ,
                        let snowUp = dict ["snowCertainAboveHeightInMeter"] as? Double ,
                        let visibility = dict ["visibilityInMeter"] as? Double ,
                        let snowProd = dict ["snowfallProbabilityInPercent"] as? Double {


                        self.datas.append(WeatherProData(date: (DateHelper.obtenir.jourDeLaSemaineWeather(dates)!) + " " + DateHelper.obtenir.dateWeatherPro(dates)! + " à " + (DateHelper.obtenir.heures(dates)!), weatherCode: weatherCodeString, temp: temp, cloud: cloud, rtemp: rtemp, cloudBase: cloudBase, dewp: dewp, press: press, hydro: hydro, vent: vent, rain: rain, iso0: iso0, freezeRain: freezeRain, noSnow: noSnow, snowUp: snowUp, visibility: visibility, snowProb: snowProd))

                      //print(weatherCodeString)

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
 }
```

The model:

```
 import UIKit

 class WeatherProData { 

private var _date: String
private var _weatherCode: String
private var _temp: Double
private var _cloud: Double
private var _rTemp: Double
private var _cloudBase: Double
private var _dewp: Double
private var _press: Double
private var _hydro: Double 
private var _vent: Double
private var _rain: Double
private var _iso0: Double
private var _freezeRain: Double
private var _noSnow: Double
private var _snowUp: Double
private var _visibility: Double
private var _snowProb: Double

var date: String {
    return _date
}

var weatherCode: String {
    return _weatherCode
}

var temp: Double {
    return _temp
}

var cloud: Double {
    return _cloud
}

var rtemp: Double {
    return _rTemp
}

var cloudBase: Double {
    return _cloudBase
}

var dewp: Double {
    return _dewp
}

var press: Double {
    return _press
}

var hydro: Double {
    return _hydro
}

var vent: Double {
    return _vent
}

var rain: Double {
    return _rain
}

var iso0: Double {
    return _iso0
}

var freezeRain: Double {
    return _freezeRain
}

var noSnow: Double {
    return _noSnow
}

var snowUp: Double {
    return _snowUp
}

var visibility: Double {
    return _visibility
}

var snowProb: Double {
    return _snowProb
}


init(date: String, weatherCode: String, temp: Double, cloud: Double, rtemp: Double, cloudBase: Double, dewp: Double, press: Double, hydro: Double, vent: Double, rain: Double, iso0: Double, freezeRain: Double, noSnow: Double, snowUp: Double, visibility: Double, snowProb: Double) {
    _date = date
    _weatherCode = weatherCode
    _temp = temp
    _cloud = cloud
    _rTemp = rtemp
    _cloudBase = cloudBase
    _dewp = dewp
    _press = press
    _hydro = hydro
    _vent = vent
    _rain = rain
    _iso0 = iso0
    _freezeRain = freezeRain
    _noSnow = noSnow
    _snowUp = snowUp
    _visibility = visibility
    _snowProb = snowProb
}
 }
```

The cell:

```
  import UIKit

 class WeatherProCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var temp: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weatherCode: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tempIcon: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var textIsHidden: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        textIsHidden.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var textIsHidden1: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        textIsHidden1.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var textIsHidden2: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        textIsHidden2.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var textIsHidden3: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        textIsHidden3.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var textIsHidden4: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        textIsHidden4.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var textIsHidden5: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        textIsHidden5.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var textIsHidden6: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        textIsHidden6.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var textIsHidden7: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        textIsHidden7.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var textIsHidden8: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        textIsHidden8.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var textIsHidden9: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        textIsHidden9.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var cloud: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        cloud.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var rTemp: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        rTemp.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var cloudBase: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        cloudBase.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var dewp: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        dewp.isHidden = true
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var press: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        press.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var pressIcon: UIImageView! {
    didSet {
        pressIcon.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var hydro: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        hydro.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var hydroIcon: UIImageView! {
    didSet {
        hydroIcon.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var vent: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        vent.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var ventIcon: UIImageView! {
    didSet {
        ventIcon.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var rainIcon: UIImageView! {
    didSet {
        rainIcon.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var rain: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        rain.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var iso0: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        iso0.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var freezeRain: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        freezeRain.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var noSnow: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        noSnow.isHidden = true
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var snowUp: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        snowUp.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var visibility: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        visibility.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var snowProb: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        snowProb.isHidden = true
    }
}


var data: WeatherProData!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

func creerCell(_ data: WeatherProData) {
    self.data = data
    let attributedDate = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.data.date)
    date.attributedText = attributedDate

    let Cloud = "\(self.data.cloud)" + " %"
    cloud.text = Cloud

    let Rtemp = "\(self.data.rtemp)" + " °C"
    rTemp.text = Rtemp

    let CloudBase = "\(self.data.cloudBase)" + " m"
    cloudBase.text = CloudBase

    let Dewp = "\(self.data.dewp)" + " °C"
    dewp.text = Dewp

    let Temp = "\(self.data.temp)" + " °C"
    temp.text = Temp
    tempIcon.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Termometre")

    let WeatherCode = "\(self.data.weatherCode)"
    weatherCode.text = WeatherCode

    let Press = "\(self.data.press)" + " hpa"
    press.text = Press
    pressIcon.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Barometre")

    let Hydro = "\(self.data.hydro)" + " %"
    hydro.text = Hydro
    hydroIcon.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Hydrometrie")

    let Vent = "\(self.data.vent)" + " km/h"
    vent.text = Vent
    ventIcon.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Vent")

    let Rain = "\(self.data.rain)" + " %"
    rain.text = Rain
    rainIcon.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Pluviometre")

    let Iso0 = "\(self.data.iso0)" + " m"
    iso0.text = Iso0

    let FreezeRain = "\(self.data.freezeRain)" + " %"
    freezeRain.text = FreezeRain

    let NoSnow = "\(self.data.noSnow)" + " m"
    noSnow.text = NoSnow

    let SnowUp = "\(self.data.snowUp)" + " m"
    snowUp.text = SnowUp

    let Visibility = "\(self.data.visibility)" + " m"
    visibility.text = Visibility

    let SnowProb = "\(self.data.snowProb)" + " %"
    snowProb.text = SnowProb
}
 }
```

I thank you in advance for your help because I have been fighting with this for 1 month

Here is the link to my GitHub to get the complete file:

https://github.com/superdevil669/MeteoWapi_iOS_App/tree/beta

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing with data sorting ? The code you provided in the link doesn't work.

Comment: In fact I would like to classify my data into sections according to date

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to modify your data model having an array holding the dates (the values for the sections) and a dictionary holding an array of the weather values for each date.
For the sake of simplicity I have 'simulated' this with String as data type.

```
// Declaration Data model
var sections = [Date]()
var datas = [Date:[String]]()

// Some test values to show how the processing could be
let date = Date()
let value = "Test"

// This would be inside your processing loop
// Check, if section already exists
if !sections.contains(date)
{
    // Add date to sections array
    sections.append(date)

    // Insert empty array in datas dictionary
    datas[date] = [String]()
}
// Add value to array
datas[date]?.append(value)

// This could be inside cellForRowAtIndexPath
// Fetch value
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

let value2 = datas[sections[indexPath.section]]?[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thanks to you, but as I'm new to the iOS development world I don't yet understand all the basics

Answer (score 0):

First of all **private backing variables to get constants is horrible in Swift**. You can declare constants simply with the `let` keyword.

If you use a `struct` you can even reduce `WeatherProData` to

```
struct WeatherProData { 

    let date: String // must be `Date` for smart grouping
    let weatherCode: String
    let temp: Double
    let cloud: Double
    let rTemp: Double
    let cloudBase: Double
    let dewp: Double
    let press: Double
    let hydro: Double
    let vent: Double
    let rain: Double
    let iso0: Double
    let freezeRain: Double
    let noSnow: Double
    let snowUp: Double
    let visibility: Double
    let snowProb: Double
}
```

because you get the `init` method for free

Grouping an array is very easy in Swift. The suggestion below assumes that `date` is declared and decoded as `Date`.
`Dictionary(grouping:by:` groups the array by the condition in the closure in this case midnight of the current date.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: datas, by: { calendar.startOfDay(for: $0.date) })
print(grouped)
```

And in Swift 4.2+ you can negate a boolean with

```
cell.textIsHidden.isHidden.toggle()
```

Consider also to use the `Deodable` protocol to get rid of the manual decoding.

Comment: Thanks to you, but as I'm new to the iOS development world I don't yet understand all the basics

Answer (score 0):

I tried another project so as not to damage mine.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

struct WeatherProData {

    let date: String // must be `Date` for smart grouping
//    let weatherCode: String
//    let temp: Double
//    let cloud: Doublea
//    let rTemp: Double
//    let cloudBase: Double
//    let dewp: Double
//    let press: Double
//    let hydro: Double
//    let vent: Double
//    let rain: Double
//    let iso0: Double
//    let freezeRain: Double
//    let noSnow: Double
//    let snowUp: Double
//    let visibility: Double
//    let snowProb: Double
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var data = [WeatherProData]()
    var sections = [Date]()
    var dataT = [Date:[String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        let date = Date()
        let value = "Test"

        if !sections.contains(date) {
            sections.append(date)
            dataT[date] = [String]()
        }

        dataT[date]?.append(value)

        var headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application.json"]

        //        Ajout lofin et mot de passe pour la connection à weather pro
        let user = loginWeatherPro
        let password = motDePasseWeatherPro

        //        Ajout de l'autorisation de connection
        if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: user, password: password) {
            headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
        }

        //        formattage de l'heure
        let now = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC")
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        print(formatter.string(from: now))
        let days = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: now)

        //        preparation de l'url de base
        let urlB = urlDeBaseWeatherPro
        let locate = "locatedAt=3.284752,50.644164"
        let period = "&validPeriod=PT0S"
        let validFrom = "&validFrom=\(formatter.string(from: now))"
        let validUntil = "&validUntil=\(formatter.string(from: days!))"
        let fields = "&fields=" + fieldsParameter
        let url = urlB + locate + period + validFrom + validUntil + fields

        Alamofire.request(url, headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                if let forecast = JSON ["forecasts"] as? NSArray {
                    for element in forecast {
                        if let dict = element as? [String: AnyObject],
                            let dates = dict ["validFrom"] as? String {
                            self.data.append(WeatherProData(date: dates))
                            print(dates)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dataT.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "test"
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let datas = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = datas.date
        return cell
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I did the simplest thing, but I can't classify my UITableView not section I think it must be due to the JSON file that sends me this as date.

```
2019-01-14T10:34:04Z
2019-01-14T12:00:00+01:00
2019-01-14T13:00:00+01:00
2019-01-14T14:00:00+01:00
2019-01-14T15:00:00+01:00
2019-01-14T16:00:00+01:00
2019-01-14T17:00:00+01:00
2019-01-14T18:00:00+01:00
2019-01-14T19:00:00+01:00
2019-01-14T20:00:00+01:00
2019-01-14T21:00:00+01:00
2019-01-14T22:00:00+01:00
2019-01-14T23:00:00+01:00
2019-01-15T00:00:00+01:00
2019-01-15T01:00:00+01:00
2019-01-15T02:00:00+01:00
2019-01-15T03:00:00+01:00
2019-01-15T04:00:00+01:00
2019-01-15T05:00:00+01:00
2019-01-15T06:00:00+01:00
2019-01-15T07:00:00+01:00
2019-01-15T08:00:00+01:00
2019-01-15T09:00:00+01:00
2019-01-15T10:00:00+01:00
2019-01-15T11:00:00+01:00
```

Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: You are encouraged to use `JSONDecoder` to decode the JSON. It's able to decode the ISO8601 string directly to `Date`. Or add an `ISO8601DateFormatter` to your struct to convert the date. And please don't `NSArray` and `[String:AnyObject]` in Swift. Use `[[String:Any]]` and `[String:Any]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying. I can create my sections but I can't display them without the hours.

I would like each section to have the title of the day, and below that the hours of each day.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

struct WeatherProData {

    let date: String // must be `Date` for smart grouping
//    let weatherCode: String
//    let temp: Double
//    let cloud: Doublea
//    let rTemp: Double
//    let cloudBase: Double
//    let dewp: Double
//    let press: Double
//    let hydro: Double
//    let vent: Double
//    let rain: Double
//    let iso0: Double
//    let freezeRain: Double
//    let noSnow: Double
//    let snowUp: Double
//    let visibility: Double
//    let snowProb: Double
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @objc func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
        // Call webservice here after reload tableview.
        tableView.reloadData()
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }

    var data = [WeatherProData]()
    var sections = [String]()
    var dateSection = [[WeatherProData]]()
    var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

//        RefrechControl sur UITableVIew
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Tirez pour rafraichir")
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)
        self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


        var headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application.json"]

        //        Ajout lofin et mot de passe pour la connection à weather pro
        let user = loginWeatherPro
        let password = motDePasseWeatherPro

        //        Ajout de l'autorisation de connection
        if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: user, password: password) {
            headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
        }

        //        formattage de l'heure
        let now = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(abbreviation: "UTC")
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        print(formatter.string(from: now))
        let days = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: now)

        let french = DateFormatter()
        french.dateStyle = .full
        french.dateFormat = "dd MMMM"
        french.locale = Locale(identifier: "FR_fr")
        print(french.string(from: now))

        //        preparation de l'url de base
        let urlB = urlDeBaseWeatherPro
        let locate = "locatedAt=3.284752,50.644164"
        let period = "&validPeriod=PT0S"
        let validFrom = "&validFrom=\(formatter.string(from: now))"
        let validUntil = "&validUntil=\(formatter.string(from: days!))"
        let fields = "&fields=" + fieldsParameter
        let url = urlB + locate + period + validFrom + validUntil + fields

        Alamofire.request(url, headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                if let forecast = JSON ["forecasts"] as? NSArray {
                    for element in forecast {
                        if let dict = element as? [String: Any],
                            let dates = dict ["validFrom"] as? String {
                            self.data.append(WeatherProData(date: dates))
                            self.sections = Array(Set(self.data.map({ (WeatherProData) -> String in
                                WeatherProData.date
                            })))
                            self.sections.forEach({ (string) in self.dateSection.append([])})
                            for index in 0..<self.sections.count {
                                self.data.forEach({ (data) in
                                    if data.date == self.sections[index] {
                                        self.dateSection[index].append(data)
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        for index in 0..<sections.count {
            if index == section {
                return dateSection[index].count
            }
        }
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
//        let datas = data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = dateSection[indexPath.section] [indexPath.row].date
//        cell.textLabel?.text = datas.date
        self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
        return cell

    }
}
```

This is what I get.

[My UITableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqXuj.png)

Answer (score 0):

In

```
self.sections = Array(Set(self.data.map({ (WeatherProData) -> String in
     WeatherProData.date
})))
```

, when you have `-> String` means that the function is asking you to return a string value. So you need to add a return with the string value in your code.

Here is a working code for your situation :

```
self.sections = Array(Set(self.data.map({ (WeatherProData) -> String in
     let jsonDateString = WeatherProData.date
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"
     if let weatherProDataDate = dateFormatter.date(from: jsonDateString) {
          return french.string(from: weatherProDataDate)
     } else {
          return ""
     }
})))
```